# How to stop python log printing in console

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am using the following code. Still my logs are being printed both in console and log file. Can anyone please help me to identify how to stop printing log in the console

```
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLog')
logger.handlers = []
hdlr = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE_PATH, maxBytes = ConfConst.MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE , backupCount= ConfConst.MAX_LOG_FILE_BACKUP_COUNT)

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] p%(process)s {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s','%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this it may help you

```py
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.disabled = True
... whatever you want ...
logger.disabled = False
```

Comment: The question is how to prevent output to `stderr` while maintaining it to a rotating file. Not how to disable it altogether.